# How to send an email using IBM Business Process Manager?

Tags: email, smtp, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I'm trying to send and email from a system task but it doesn't work.

The task I'm using is Send email with SMTP sending this parameters:

[image]

Should I specify a smtpHost? And if so, how do I know what to put there?